# Python searching CSV using cell from xlsx

Tags: python, excel, csv, xlrd

Im trying to read each cell from a row in a .xlsx file, store that in a varible, then search another .csv row by row for that string. The string contains multiple spaces.

Sample of string:
MM DETAILS AS CATS NUMBER HAS CHANGEDNEW CATS DETAILS DOGS

If that row contains that string, I think want to print that row.

```
from __future__ import print_function
from xlrd import open_workbook
from os.path import join, dirname, abspath
import xlrd
import csv

fname = join(dirname(dirname(abspath(__file__))), 'root', 'excel.xlsx')

xl_workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(fname)

xl_sheet = xl_workbook.sheet_by_index(1)

row = xl_sheet.row(0)

for row_idx in range(0, xl_sheet.nrows):
        cell_val = str(xl_sheet.cell_value(row_idx, 4))
        with open('cvs.csv') as f:
#debug      print (cell_val)
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            for row in reader:
                    if cell_val in row:
                            print('Found: {}'.format(row))
```

But this just nothing at all, when search for the string in the csv document inside excel I can easily find it, I'm unsure what is wrong.

Any help would be AMAZING! Thanks in advance.

Comment: I meant to say: "But this returns nothing at all,"

Comment: You can edit your question.

Comment: can you share a little sample of your excel and csv file.

Comment: Your code currently searches the second sheet in the workbook. Is that what you want?